# Concatenate values except when equal to string

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Please some help. With this DAX formula I concatenate all unique values of `Column3`

```
Column4 = CONCATENATEX(
VALUES(Table1[Column3]),Table1[Column3],", ")
```

with result

```
ABC,DEF,WXYZ,HHT
```

My issue is that I would like to concatenate all unique values, except the value "WXYZ"

I've tried this:

```
Column4 = CALCULATE(
        CONCATENATEX(
 VALUES(Table1[Column3]),Table1[Column3],", "),
       FILTER ( Table1, 
FIND( "WXYZ", Table1[Column3],, 0 ) = 0 )
)
```

But I get `circular dependency was detected: Table1[Column4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution would be something the following - filter the table first and then concatenate:

```
CONCATENATEX
    (
        DISTINCT(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Column3] <> "WXYZ"))
        ,Table1[Column3]
        ,", "
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Barney for your help. Your solution excludes the not wanted string but the output shows all values, not only the unique values. How to modify your formula in order the output shows unique values without the not wanted string?

Comment: @Ger-cas It's as simple as using the DISTINCT function! See the edited version. Note that DISTINCT eliminates null values.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and solution. How to use Distinct function is what I had missing.

Comment: I've tried adding DISTINCT and the output is showing all values of column3 without the value WXYZ. So, the not wanted value is not shown but still is not showing the unique values

Comment: I think it must be running the distinct on the entire table not the one column. Try FILTER(DISTINCT(Table1[Column3]),Table1[Column3] <> "WXYZ"). Otherwise it probably needs rearranging to use CALCULATE to apply the filter.

Comment: Thanks BarneyL for your help